# How to draw a surface from scattered data in Scilab?

Tags: plot, surface, scilab

How can I plot such a thing shown in the Fig with Scilab.

[image: Sample photo here]

For example, There is a value of coupling loss at the location of (X,Y). So, there is a certain Z value for each (X, Y) points but the value is not a function of this (X,Y).

Any help is appreciated.

I expect it to be look exactly like in this figure, or 3D surface plot as.

Comment: You've listed 3 languages, please narrow it down to one or this is too broad. What have you tried and what are you stuck with _specifically_? Have you generated the data? Have you generated the plot but need to add the colours? Can you make a [mcve] up to the point you're stuck? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unstructured data like this one (z as an unknown function of scattered (x,y) data) the only way is to use a triangulation of (x,y) data and plot resulting triangles in the 3d space, like in this example

```
x=rand(50,1);
y=rand(50,1);
z=rand(50,1);
tri = mesh2d(x, y);
gcf().color_map=parulacolormap(128);
plot3d1(x(tri),y(tri),z(tri));
gce().hiddencolor=0;
```

[image]